# Using clr for adhesive

Tags: tile

I peeled up my peel and stick vinyl flooring in my kitchen without any heat and there's alot of adhesive left. Could I use clr to get the rest of the adhesive off? I'm stick more vinyl down after I get the floor cleaned!

Comment: You could, but doubt it will do any good.  What you plan to use is a weak acid that helps with removal of calcium, lime and rust.  Google tile adhesive removal for better ideas.

Comment: CLR would not work as an adhesive remover, there are citrus based adhesive removers that work great for picking up the adhesive residue. Goo gone is one brand of general remover that many stores carry that will work.